# Push notification issue on Worklight 6.2 with windows 2008

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We're having a problem receiving push notifications on 6.2 running on windows 2008 server.
We were receiving notifications when running on a red hat linux environment, but for some reason our organization decided to switch from linux to windows.

The liberty version is 8.5.5.0 and using IBM jre 1.7_64

The exception in the messages.log is:

> 0000a62 com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator E FPWSE1067E: An Exception occurred in the mediator.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Not yet implemented
>       at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator.updateDeviceSubscriptionByToken(Mediator.java:130)
>       at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.updateDeviceSubsciption(GCMMediator.java:172)
>       at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMSender.sendAndVerify(GCMSender.java:169)
>       at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.sendOrWait(GCMMediator.java:139)
>       at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.gcm.GCMMediator.sendNotification(GCMMediator.java:128)
>       at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Mediator$2.run(Mediator.java:87)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:482)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:345)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:177)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)

Comment: can you let us know the status of this question?

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and saw that installing latest version resolving this. I tried with v7 version... this issue doesn't occur.

For Worklight 6.2 and others, there is APAR PI32603 that resolves this issue - so make sure you are upgrading to the latest available iFix.